# how to find out DOM through selenium java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I am running the below code to get the text value of the "alternateId" of window.CONTET_MODEL.allVideos.0 by using selnium + JAVA in the attached DOM structure. please lete me know what should be the Script????

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String script = "return ???";
WebElement element = (WebElement) js.executeScript(script);
element.getText();
```

Comment: Try with the script   "return window.CONTENT_MODEL.allVideos[0]._attributes[0]"

Comment: It did not work. it gives exception of  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: you can try by navigating to the https://www.discoverykidsplay.com/ and try through DOM to find out the href of the first video or the first video which is having packages => "Free"

Comment: It is working for me. it returns the text "alternateId"

Comment: What value do you want to extract?

Comment: Actually I need href whose packages=Registered so that I would get element.getText() something like /video/annedroids/experimento-de-ninera

Comment: you can try the following window.CONTENT_MODEL.allVideos[0].alternateId

Comment: This will return href value window.CONTENT_MODEL.allVideos[0].href

Comment: I tried with Driver.driver.get("https://www.discoverykidsplay.com");
        Wait.wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#root"))); JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     WebElement element = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return window.CONTENT_MODEL.allVideos[0].href;");
    System.out.print(element.getText()); and it gives me the error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Comment: Don't cast to web element. It will return string only. Just assign to string.

Comment: Done that and it worked as   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String element = (String) js.executeScript("return window.CONTENT_MODEL.allVideos[0].href;");
System.out.print(element); How to add that condition that the packages should be free

Comment: please try the following.var videos=window.CONTENT_MODEL.allVideos;for(var i=0,j;i<videos.length;i++){if(videos[i].packages[0]=="Free"){videos[i].href;break;}}

Comment: thanks. it worked as I used href = (String) js.executeScript("var videos=window.CONTENT_MODEL.allVideos;for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++){if(videos[i].packages[0]==\"Free\"){return videos[i].href;}}");